# Android Dagger and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, dagger

I am using Dagger dependency injection.  It normally works fine but when I am using it to inject a component into a class that extends FirebaseInstanceIdService it fails the build.  Is there something special about FirebaseInstanceIdService that prevents me from injecting into it or is there something I need to do to get it to work.  I am not trying to inject an instance of the FirebaseInstanceIdService anywhere, just inject a dependancy into it

AppComponent has

```
void inject (AbcFirebaseInstanceIdService abcFirebaseInstanceIdService);
```

And the AbcFirebaseInstanceIdService  has

```
public void inject(ApplicationComponent appComponent) {
        appComponent.inject(this);
    }
```

Comment: what calls the public void inject wth its application component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2
```

does not seem to work with

```
com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1.
```

Having seen MikeNs code worked with an older version of dagger, made me try and upgrade my dagger version to 2.6.1.  The same code that would not compile before now compiles.

Comment: Days of headache were resolved by simply updating the version.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting. This works within our codebase

```
public class NYTFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
      @Inject Lazy<Foo> foo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        buildObjectGraphAndInject();
    }

    private void buildObjectGraphAndInject() {
        getComponent().inject(this);
    }

    protected Component getComponent() {
        return ComponentFactory().create();
    }
}
```

Comment: It fails the project build as it does when I have made any error when setting up the dependency injection with dagger.  

D:\yyy\\app\src\main\java\apppathname\App.java
Error:(14, 39) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerApplicationComponent

I am using com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2